# How do I properly install a fan in my computer case?

Tags: installation, fan

I have a new desktop PC with Intel Core 2 duo. I now just buy a cabinet fan and I need to place it on the back side of the cabinet just below the SMPS. How can I place it there with appropriate position? What I mean is I need the direction which the fan should rotate so that there will be a cooling inside the cabinet..

Comment: I don't understand this question. Normally, as case designed for a fan under the power supply has a fan grill w/ screw holes to hold the fan in place. So, normally, the answer is "by screwing it in". But you must be asking something else?

Comment: I need the rotation direction so that it can cool the inside of cabinet?

Comment: Can't you plug it in and see which way the air flows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some references.

- eHow -- [**How to Install Computer Case Fans**](http://www.ehow.com/how_2122082_install-computer-case-fans.html)
- [**Computer Case Fans: Installing, Replacing, Cooling**](http://www.monkeyseemonkeydobooks.com/computer-case-fans.html)
- Building a PC: [**Installing Fans**](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/hardware/articles/10105.aspx)

---

You are interested in the direction of the air flow (push-in or pull-out).

- The usual thing to do is pull-out.
- It helps if there is a side-grill on the cabinet, a little below the processor location and the fan actually is aligned close to the processor (usually the case with a good cabinet & motherboard combination).
  In this setup, the cabinet fan creates a good air flow around the processor sink+fan.
- Sometimes, the processor comes with its own 'vent' through a side-grill, that has a 'funnel' path from the processor sink to outside. With such setups, a side fan only introduces unwanted turbulence around the processor fan. Care is required in such setups.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking airflow in a PC should be front-to-back.

The 80mm and 120mm fans you get in a PC typically have the direction of airflow stamped on them in the form of a little arrow, so you know which way around to install them.